# zend framework insert data without key value

Tags: database, zend-framework

you can use insert like `Insert into table values()` . If the number of values correspond to the number of table fields the insert will be executed.

I want to use this feature in `$this->_db->insert('table',$data)` , where data is an array I get from fgetcsv.

Is this possible? Regards Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `$data`conforms to `@param array $bind Column-value pairs` it'll work.

So your array from the csv has to be a associative array where the ***keys = column names*** and ***values = column values***.

Good Luck!